# How to disassemble Ubicom32 binaries?

Tags: embedded, ubicon32

I cannot figure out how to disassemble these binaries I pulled from a wireless router I recently came into possession of.

file output:

```
httpd: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

binwalk output:

```
DECIMAL         HEX             DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0               0x0             ELF 32-bit MSB executable, Ubicom32, version 1 (SYSV)
```

`IDA` doesn't seem to disassemble it correctly. `gobjdump` doesn't seem to have any matching targets for it.

Am I just missing something obvious? How should I disassemble this?